# Which folders are often written to, and how can I mount those folders on a separate drive?

Tags: server, filesystem, usb-drive, live-usb, headless

I have a headless ubuntu server acting as a fileserver (samba and ssh) and sometimes virtualbox host.
It is currently running from a USB drive, since all hard drive slots on the motherboard are occupied.

Since any OS can be rather write happy, and flash memory drives have limited write lifespan , I want to minimize the number of writes the OS makes to the drive.

I have already moved the swap files to one of the hard drives. Can I mount any other 'chatty' folders on the hard drives as well? (I imagine /var/log makes a few writes ever so often)

Which folders in a normal base ubuntu install are often written to, and how can I mount those folders on a separate drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) specifies:

> /var contains variable data files

So moving `/var` should have the biggest impact.

If you have enough RAM, you could also mount `/tmp` as `tmpfs` because it usually contains only small files which don't have to be persistent between reboots. In fact the FHS even says:

> Programs must not assume that any files or directories in /tmp are preserved between invocations of the program.